# \input inside \href

Tags: hyperref, tex-core, input

I have a number of papers that include my email on the cover of the paper, and need to find a solution to `\input` my email address using `\href`. This way I will be able to edit my email once, and then get the most updated email address in all my papers every time I compile the file.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
\href{mailto:{\input{/Path/to/my/file/with/my/email/address.txt}\unskip}}{{\input{/Path/to/my/file/with/my/email/address.txt}\unskip}}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: you could but why make it so complicated, rather than `\href{mailto:\myemail}{\myemail}` together with a `myemail.sty` that you can put in your input path with just one line: `\def\myemail{foo@example.com}`

Comment: If you are trying to remove the space that TeX adds after the sheer contents of your file (because it adds an end-of-line marker), `\unskip` cannot be used for this purpose in the first argument of `\href`.  In principle, the problem could be cured by setting `\endlinechar = -1`,  but it is *much* more simple to act as @DavidCarlisle suggests (but replacing `\def` with `\newcommand*`, I’d say…).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses plain TeX I/O commands.

```
\begin{filecontents}{address.txt}
jkormylo@elfsoft2000.com
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newread\fid

\newcommand{\readfile}[1]% #1 = filename
{\bgroup
  \endlinechar=-1
  \openin\fid=#1
  \read\fid to\filetext
  \loop\ifx\empty\filetext\relax% skip over comments
    \read\fid to\filetext
  \repeat
  \closein\fid
  \global\let\filetext=\filetext
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\readfile{address.txt}
\href{mailto:\filetext}{\filetext}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution that fetches the mail address from a file to a macro via package `catchfile`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{address.txt}
john.doe@example.org
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\CatchFileDef\TheMailAddress{address.txt}{\endlinechar=-1}
% \endlinechar=-1 suppresses spaces by line ends

\begin{document}
\href{mailto:\TheMailAddress}{John Doe $\langle$\TheMailAddress$\rangle$}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Just for curiosity: how do you make the screenshots with transparent background?

Comment: @samcarter Usually, I convert to PDF, crop it, and run it through ghostscript's device `pngalpha`. Here, I have used the device `png16m` and used Gimp's "Colorize to alpha", because the current installed ghostscript (9.19) creates ugly artefacts at the edges.

Comment: @samcarter I guess that it's not a screnshot. Rather a pdf that was converted into a gif or png.

Comment: Sorry. Wasn't reading it accurate enough. The question wasn't of course not for me :). Still, have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick. I use the convert command from the windows command window or in a batch file for that kind of tasks.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for your reply! This workflow sounds useful!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner :) The more people to answer the better :)

Comment: @samcarter Just tested, ghostscript 9.21 seems to have the issue (color artifacts at the edges) fixed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for letting me know! Fortunately(?) my ghostscript version is from the pre-bug area :)

Comment: thanks a lot, will explore some more this great package! @HeikoOberdiek